# 'DataGrid1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Please help: 
I am getting this error when debugging
'DataGrid1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. vb.net

the whole code is as follows:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1

    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
        Create ADO.NET objects.
        Private myConn As SqlConnection
        Private myCmd As SqlCommand
        Private myReader As SqlDataReader
        Private results As String
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'Create a Connection object.
        myConn = New SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=dbo.DispatchedBranches;User ID=Guestdmin2;Password=KL9791/*" &
                "Data Source=LP2012-HP\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;")

        'Create a Command object.
        myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand
        myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM DispatchedBranches"

        'Open the connection.
        myConn.Open()

        myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()

        'Concatenate the query result into a string.
        Do While myReader.Read()
            results = results & myReader.GetString(0) & vbTab &
        myReader.GetString(1) & vbLf
        Loop
        'Display results.
        MsgBox(results)

        'Insert a line of code before the DataReader and Connection objects are closed in the Form1_Load event procedure. 
        'The end of the procedure should appear as follows

        SqlDataAdapter1.Fill(DataSet1, "DispatchedBranches")
        myReader.Close()
        myConn.Close()


    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick


        DataGrid1.SetDataBinding(DataSet1, "DispatchedBranches")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you set `DataGrid1` Properties > Modifiers to True?

Comment: the availabel options are 'Public', private protected, protected,protected friend and private;

Comment: whats the name of your grid control? `DataGridView1` or `DataGrid1`? i see you have this `Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(..)`

Comment: Based on the `Handles` clause I'd say the name is `DataGridView1`, if they're the same.